Running Scrapy via subprocess.run doesn't run via frontend api only runs via thunderclient and the likes
So i have a scapy spider nd i integrated it with my drf project by using subprocess.run but there's an issue the api call only runs successfully when i test it with thunderclient but when i try it by making an api call on my frontend it doesn't work and always returns the err: subprocess failed to execute
here is my code:

def create(self, request):
serializer = SearchSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
search_value = request.data.get('value')
category_value = request.data.get('category')
user_id = request.user.id

try:
if category_value == "Politics":
result = run(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'politicsblog', '-a', f'search={search_value}', '-a', f'user_id={user_id}'], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
elif category_value == "Fashion":
result = run(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'fashionblog', '-a', f'search={search_value}', '-a', f'user_id={user_id}'], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)

if 'result' in locals() and result:
logger.info(f"Subprocess stdout: {result.stdout}")
logger.error(f"Subprocess stderr: {result.stderr}")

serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
return Response({"message": "Search started successfully", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
logger.error("Subprocess failed to execute")
return Response({'error': 'Subprocess failed to execute'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

except CalledProcessError as e:
logger.error(f"Subprocess error: {e}")
return Response({'error': 'Error running subprocess', 'detail': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

except Exception as ex:
logger.error(f"Exception occurred: {ex}")
return Response({'error': 'Unexpected error occurred'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


I have made tons of changes to my frontend and tried error hanling with the logging module, i was expecting like a 4.5s delay before the post request is complete but nothing worked, i said a 4.5s delay because that's roughly how long it takes when i test it with thunder client

well I've tried all i could possibly try but to no avail but i ended up using scrapyd worked fine on my system but i can't say yet for when i host it, hopefully it works fine too
